# Not able to get the folder path of azure storage gen2 of file systems

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-lake

I have created a logic app,i'm reading file from datalake and need to load that to storage gen2 in azure.I have created connection for storage gen 2 using the action azure file storage and need to create the file in the file system.i have full access for the azure storage gen 2.But i'm not able to see the folder path for that connection.Can some one help me on this issue?
Thanks in advance.Below is the screen shot

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-e4yK5j6dYG0/XNwThtU9HCI/AAAAAAAABfg/MqodPgFOTqA5u1Owg7sTVd8VNuhau1LOwCK8BGAs/s0/2019-05-15.png

Answer (score 0):

I test if you don't have File share, in the Logic App it will show no items.

So go to your Azure File Storage, add `File share`, then go to Logic App, refresh your page and it will show your File share.

[image]